# sql - python syntax error making view and selecting data

Tags: python, sql

hi and hope you have a good time , i was making an app in python and SQL and i'm getting a syntax error in SQL , can you help?

```
self.mycursor.execute(f'''CREATE VIEW [usable products] AS
            SELECT * FROM products
            WHERE {str(self.counts.value())}> (SELECT count FROM products)
            ''')
```

and the error is :

```
ight syntax to use near '[usable products] AS
            SELECT * FROM products
            WHER' at line 1

version for the right syntax to use near '[usable products] AS
            SELECT * FROM products
            WHER' at line 1
```

thank you!

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using which vary in SQL dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterizing your query and avoiding F-string interpolation. Also, the subquery is not necessary if `count` (not mistaken for `COUNT()` aggregate) is a column in `products` table.

Below assumes you are using `pyodbc` or `sqlite3` which use qmarks, `?`, for parameter placeholders. If using other DB-APIs (`psycopg2`, `pymysql`, etc.) use `%s` placeholder.

```py
sql = (
    "CREATE VIEW [usable products] AS "
    "   SELECT * FROM products "
    "   WHERE count < ?"
)

self.mycursor.execute(sql, [self.counts.value()])
```